# Wrap URL (ignores margin) in BibTeX using pdfLaTeX

Tags: url, latex, margin, pdflatex, bibtex

I'm using the breakurl package and the hyperref package with pdfLatex and BibTeX to cite a url. The url is breaking, but not according to my margins. Is there any way I can make the url recognize my margins or force a line break? Thanks in advance.

Code:

`\usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[vertfit]{breakurl}`

```
@MISC{cmm:dataset,
author = {University of Bristol Centre for Multilevel Modelling},
    title = {Datasets used in reviews},
    howpublished = {\url{http://www.cmm.bristol.ac.uk/learning-training/multilevel-m-software/exam.shtml}},
}
```

Comment: Note also that you have a specialized stack* site for TeX/LaTeX: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I will post there in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, when LaTeX cannot break lines nicely, it leaves them unadjusted. You can control that behavior putting `\sloppy` at the beginnig of your document and see if the behavior suits you more. Also, you have spaces in your URL, as I've seen in your post. Remove them. The `url` package usuallly does a nice job breaking urls (I have not used the `breakurl` package and my URLs break nicely by the slashes or dashes).

Comment: Thanks, I will try the \sloppy command. The url doesn't actually have any spaces, must have been a typo on my part. Sorry about that!

EDIT: The \sloppy command took care of it. Thanks again!

Comment: Using `\sloppy` is, as a general rule, a *very*, **very** bad idea. The `url` package is the way to go: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=citeURL

Comment: Thanks Konrad. I was using the url package at first, but it neglected my margins. Can you tell me why using \sloppy for this one instance is a bad idea?

Comment: @Andee: [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/) calls the use of `\sloppy` a “deadly sin”. Refer to that document for details.

Comment: The `url` package, by default, only breaks at `.` and `/`, not at `-`. So, `http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/activision-blizzard-announces-better-than-expected-first-quarter-2012-financial-results-150831155.html` still eats on the margin (by a lot). Solution: `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/forcing-linebreaks-in-url

Comment: @gentimouton I think that your solution of adding [hyphens] warrants it's own Answer.  That's what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Better to add 'breaklinks' to the options for hyperref or if using url explicitly format the url in the bibtex file "\url{http:....}".  This fixed the problem for me.  You may still need to redefine the format for the url if the default box does not suit your purposes.